# ReactJS prop function becomes undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I can't figure out where this 'function' become or is undefined. Let me explain before reading code.\ App render Shows, Shows render multiple Show extracted from 'show' state. But if you change to FAVS tab, Shows Show will be extracted from 'favs' state. 
if you want test it your self: <removed-repo>

To reproduce:

1. Press add.
2. Press `FAVS` tab.
3. Remove the added show.

Surce:

```
const [shows, setShows] = useState([])
const [favs, setFavs] = useState([])
const [fav, setFav] = useState(false)
```

```
return (
    <div className="application">
      <FullWidthTabs setFav={setFav} filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} /> 
      <div id="mainBody" className="container text-center">
        <ul id="results">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <footer className="text-center">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              { // error -------------
                fav === true
                  ? <Shows addRemoveFav={addRemoveFav} fav={fav} shows={showFavs()} />
                  : <Shows addRemoveFav={addRemoveFav} fav={fav} shows={showShows()} />
              } // -------------------
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
```

```
  const addRemoveFav = (show) => {
    if (favs.length != 0) {
      const result = favs.filter(fav => show.show_id == fav.show_id)
      if (result.length < 1) {
        setFavs(favs.concat(show))
      } else {
        setFavs(favs.filter(fav => fav.show_id !== show.show_id))
      }
    } else {
      setFavs(favs.concat(show))
    }
  }
```

```
const Shows = ({ shows, addRemoveFav }) => {

    console.log('ADD REMOVE FAV JODER');
    console.log(addRemoveFav);

    const showList = () => shows.map(show => 
        <Show addRemoveFav={addRemoveFav} key={show.show_id} show={show} />
    )

    if (shows.length === 1) return <Show show={shows[0]} />
    if (shows.length < 10 && shows.length > 0) return <>{showList()}</>
    if (shows.length > 20) return <p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>
    return <p>No matches</p>
}
```

```
const Show = ({ show, addRemoveFav }) => {
// ( .... )
return (
// ( .... )
<button
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-outline-success btn-floating"
    data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"
    onClick={() => addRemoveFav(show)} // here it sends current show object
/>
```

Comment: I don't see you define a `fav` variable in the first component, maybe that's the problem? There's the `favs` variable, but that's an array

Comment: @CertainPerformance there is a `fav` variable with a type of boolean. he just didint display it in the actual post. I checked his source

Comment: @AdriGB Since the `fav` seems to be what you're worried about, please edit your question to include where it's defined and changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main errors

**1st.** The error `Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined` is NOT caused by any variable, component or even react code. Its inside your `index.html`. Removing the script line `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-log-state"></script>` fixes the error. Move it inside a react component since it requires something from react itself and you execute it before react.

**2nd.** The `cannot appear as a descendant of <p>`. Its caused by `<Typography>{children}</Typography>`, in `function TabPanel(props)` in `FullWidthTabs.js`. Your `children` contains `div` and other highter elements, but the `Typography` returns a `p`. A paragraph shouldn't contain containers, but just simple text.

**3rd.** In the cards below, after you do a search, after you click the Star icon, the crash happened because of this line here `if (shows.length === 1) return <Show show={shows[0]} />` inside your `Show.js`. It ONLY happens when you have ONLY 1 card. Its because you never pass the value `addRemoveFav` to the component `Show` when it's only 1 (aka `if === 1`). This exist in both `Netflix` and `Favorite` page as long as its exactly one card. To fix it its simple: pass in the property `addRemoveFav` like so `if (shows.length === 1) return <Show show={shows[0]} addRemoveFav={addRemoveFav} />;` and it fixes your issue.

The reason this is not an issue when you have 2+ cards, is because with more than 1 card, you execute `showList` function that returns a mapped array of `<Show addRemoveFav={addRemoveFav} key={show.show_id} show={show} />` with `Show` components that have `addRemoveFav` property.

**Suggestions**

Some suggestions to improve your code

**1st.** The rendering. You have this

```
<Col>
  {
    fav === true
      ? <Shows addRemoveFav={onDelete} fav={fav} shows={showFavs()} />
      : <Shows addRemoveFav={onDelete} fav={fav} shows={showShows()} />
  }
</Col>
```

It breaks the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle as the code itself is repeated multiple times with only change - the data given to `shows` prop. You can easily fix it with:

```
<Col>
  <Shows
    addRemoveFav={onDelete}
    fav={fav}
    shows={fav ? showFavs() : showShows()}
  />
</Col>
```

The idea is still the same. But now you do not have to repeat the code twice.

**2nd.** You do not require to do `fav === true ? "" : ""`. JavaScript is amazing when it comes to validating values. A simple `fav ? "" : ""` will do it. JavaScript will return `false` if the value, in this case, `fav` is a `null`, `undefined`, an empty string or `false`. Could be even more, don't remember from the top of my head.

This also works with simple `if` statements. In addition, you can even do this `{fav && <div>render me</div>}`. If at the end, HAS to be the end, of an validation is some sort of react child, in this case, `div`, it will return that react child. The check can be as complex as you wish `{((fav && try) || (!fav && number > 5)) && <div>render me with condition</div>}`

**3rd.** Split up your components. Noticed that there are multiple functional components in a single file (mainly `App`). It kinda breaks the Single responsibility principle as the file is responsible for multiple stuff. In addition, the file becomes large and the components are hard to re-use. Simply make a new file for each new functional, or class, component.

**4th.** Shorter returns. Sometimes you will have functions that you know will be a single line of code to return something. For example this:

```
const showFavs = () => {
  return favs.filter((show) =>
    JSON.stringify(show).toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
  );
};
```

You could simply do:

```
const showFavs = () =>
  favs.filter((show) =>
    JSON.stringify(show).toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
  );
```

It's not a requirement. A lot of times you will see such functions with a return statement because some people prefer it like that. It's just good to know you can do this.

**5th.** `Console.log()`. To console you don't have to pass in only strings or variables. You can actually combine a string and an array, function, or anything else, into a single line. So instead of:

```
console.log("ADD REMOVE FAV JODER");
console.log(addRemoveFav);
```

Do `console.log("ADD REMOVE FAV JODER", addRemoveFav);`. Your console will be less filled with spam when testing. Also kinda easier to navigate.

**6th.** OnClick execute the function on the spot. Instead of creating a new function `const tryToFix = () => addRemoveFav(show);` just to pass it to  `onClick={tryToFix}` is kinda useless. You don't do any kind of logic inside it. So you can execute it on the spot without any new function `onClick={() => addRemoveFav(show)}`. NOTE, if you executing the function (like `function()`) rather then just passing a reference (like `function`) you HAVE to use an arrow, or simple, function `() =>` since than it will be executed on load rather then onClick.

**7th.** Make the code pretty! After loading up your file, my IDE had a fun time reforming it. If you using VSC (for react would recommend it), install an extension called `Prettier`. Works with many many many different languages, including react. And is fully customizable if you want to change something. After installing it, you will need to go to the settings to enable it `OnSave`, so whenever you save a file, it will re-format your code to make it pretty.

Hope these suggestions helped. You might have known some, might have not. It's always good to know these basics.

Comment: react-log-state is a library which I try to get deeper logs (but it was useless for me so this script is not currently doing nothing). I've removed that script, but error stays equal.
Note that error is 'TypeError: addRemoveFav is not a function'

Comment: @AdriGB I updated my post revolving hte other error and with a request of how we could help u.

Comment: It is ready. I'm sorry for being late, its 2:20 a.m here :,D

Comment: It someone try github code, write unique mock show 'title' on search bar to reproduce crash

Comment: @AdriGB the crash when you click the star icon in the card?

Comment: Yes, It crashes when click the star on Fav tab, not netflix tab

Comment: It craches on both. Ill post the reason real quickly. give me  amin or to. its 4am :)

Comment: @AdriGB I updated the post with a reason to why you getting `undefined` error.

Comment: Omg, I want a bit of your concentration... tomorrow I will do this for sure! Thanks so much,

Comment: @AdriGB Your welcome. In addition, i included few tips/suggestions that i noticed from a quick look at ur code, These are some basics that are good to folow/know. Happy developing!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will carefully take a look at this tips :)

Comment: I recently learned how to mark as correct... Sorry xD It's a bit late but it was a nice answer